# Way of Thinking CSS classes

Tags: css, refactoring

I'm thinking about css refacto in my job, and i'm wondering if it's a good idea (considering best practices) to create css class with only one property.

A simple example, is it usefull to create many classes this way

```
.center-text {
    text-align: center;
}
```

What's the best between doing this or using small libs like Knacss (if you know it) for example.

Answer (score 2):

### *BIGGEST PROBLEM WITH CSS CLASSES*: THEIR LOCATION INSIDE YOUR FILE / CODE MATTERS!!

lets assume we have this html element:

```
<div class="test altr">some text</div>
```

this css file:

```
.test
{
    color: red;
}

.altr
{
    color: blue;
}
```

will result in a blue text (the div has those 2 classes). **BUT** this file will result with a red color:

```
.altr
{
    color: blue;
}

.test
{
    color: red;
}
```

the order of command in css is determine by the css file (and not the order inside the html class attribute)

not to mention that the physical order between  and  tags inside your html alo affects the order of commands in css (last command override all previous commands)

so.. whatever you do - **please be careful with that**

Answer (score 0):

One minor drawback I see is the amount of text in your HTML will increase slightly due to pile up of classes. Not best SEO practices, but it's minor.